# python timing out of a function if takes a long time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, signals

Let's say I have a function

```
def may_take_a_long_time():
    while 1:
        # do something
        if met_condition():
            break

timeout_dur = 600
may_take_a_long_time()
do_something_else()
```

What can I do so that if `may_take_a_long_time()` takes longer than `timeout_dur`, to abort whatever its doing, and proceed w/ `do_something_else()`

perhaps, setting `SIGALARM` before calling `may_take_a_long_time()`? how do i do that? or run `may_take_a_long_time()` in a thread which happens async so i can have `time.sleep(timeout_dur)` in caller's thread?

Comment: there is a handy [timeout decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator) you could use.

Comment: `multiprocessing` also supports timeouts natively if that is what you are using

Comment: @Ev.Kounis fyi, im using timeout decorate you've provided and it works great. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Threading in python has quirks, and if you want an answer specific to that, I suggest you edit your question and put that up front.

For simple single threaded, you could use the existing timeout decorator as another user suggested or you can make your own, or you can do something like this (you'll have to tailor the code if you expect may_take_a_long_time() to return something, though:

```
import time

def may_take_a_long_time(tout):
    timeout = time.time() + tout
    passed = False

    while not passed:
        passed = met_condition()
        if time.time() > timeout:
            break

def met_condition():
   if some_condition:
      return True
   else:
      return False           

def do_something_else():
   # TODO your code here

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    may_take_a_long_time(30)
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: you are assuming that met_condition() is async. what if it doesnt return for greater than timeout. then you cant do check inside the loop

Comment: I was under the impression that met_condition() returned a boolean. Therefore, it could not be compared with a timeout. The timeout is a separate check to break out of the while loop. Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly?